# What is "superficial density" in the context of integration (over surfaces)?

Tags: integration, definition

I have read something like this:

> We have
>   $$\int_{M}f(x)d\sigma(x) = 1$$
>   where $d\sigma$ is the superficial density.

What does this mean? $M$ is a hypersurface/manifold. The author does not define it.

Comment: "Superficial" means pertaining to a surface.  But I can't say more than that.  Maybe it just means density with respect to surface area.

Comment: What author, what paper/book, what language?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you, that's what i think.

Comment: @WillJagy It is Demengel & Dimengel, the book on PDEs in English. They are talking about a norm on $W^{s,p}$ space in the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia article [Area density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_density) begins with

> The area density (also known as areal density, surface density, or superficial density) ...

In mathematics, it is more common to call this "surface measure".